# Echo $_SESSION on button click (WITHOUT page refresh)

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a online cafe menu on website and I add products to shopping cart with sending request by ajax. I need to display changes made to `$_SESSION` on every its update (when I increase or decrease amount of products) but without page refresh. Is it possible? Now I echo session like this

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){
  foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $values) {
    echo "<tr>
      <td>"; echo $values['item_name'];  echo "</td>
      <td>"; echo $values['item_qty'];   echo "</td>
      <td>"; echo $values['item_price']; echo"</td>
    </tr>";
  }
}
```

But it echo new items only on page refresh, how to fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's possible with the technique you've already tagged the question with: Ajax. If you want more help, you need to include _all_ relevant code and explain what `$_SESSION['shopping_cart']` contains and how it's updated. There's nothing in the posted code that gives us any clue into how you're using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Was needed to set a delay between ajax post and div (where the shopping cart is displayed) refresh.

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $("#orders_body").load('appendOrders.php');
    }, 500);
```